# How to prevent memory leaks in a streaming http/s server in node.js?

Tags: node.js, real-time, long-polling

I built a streaming https server that polls a back-end service and writes the data to the http client if it is available. The code for a specific https request looks like this somehow:

```
// check for new stuff periodically
var timer = setInterval( function() {
                   var resp = getResponseObject();
                   response.write(resp + "\n\r");
               }, 500);

// stop looping when the client disconnects
request.on('close', function() {
             clearInterval(timer);
             return;
             });
```

When the client disconnects, the time-out gets cleared and the loop stops. But will this on-close event always be triggered? Also on a not-so-clean client disconnect? I worry about leaving loops behind for connections that are no longer in place.
Any idea if this is safe? Other approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you need to worry about "unclean" disconnects -- when the client machines are abruptly removed from the network, your server will eventually get either TCP `FIN` packets or ICMP Destination Unreachable messages, which will trigger the `close` event in your server and allow you to clean up.

What is probably more resource intensive would be hundreds or thousands of clients sending and receiving data *so slowly* that you wind up running out of file descriptors for all the network sockets. A client that connects with ridiculously low [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Maximum_segment_size) could force your application to dribble megabytes down a connection in 100-byte chunks for days or weeks.